# Struggling with hasclass() function

Tags: jquery

am struggling with some jquery funciton.

I have a series of tabs (using Foundation 5), that when a tab active each shows a different image. I figured to use a hasClass() function but I can't even get that to work :(.

Here is the code.

```
  <script>
if($( "#test").hasClass("test2")) {
  alert ("works")} 
else {
  alert ("no works")} 
}

</script>
```

Once a panel has a class, I'd like to add an image to a div called "image-holder"

Comment: I dont think you can use echo, did you define that function? Instead try console.log() or alert()

Comment: Buddy you are mixing Javascript and PHP

Comment: gotcha, thanks... I thought and was trying different stuff since I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code has an extra }

Here is an example of it working.[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/uooj4h3m/)

```
if($( "#test").hasClass("test2")) {
alert ("works")} 
else {
alert ("no works")}
```

In the fiddle, remove the class test2 and run the code to see your other alert